# How to check method or property visibility without Reflection?

Tags: php, reflection

I'm writing a simple php framwork. Now I need a better way to check if a method or property is private or public. Currently I'm using the Reflection class for that, but as it's needed on nearly every property access.

I need it for the magic `__get` which will allow you to call `$object->testProperty` if there's a public method `getTestProperty()` in it.

I'm looking for an other way to do this (because of the performance). Is there any faster possibility?

Comment: can you please explain why that should be needed? Your objects should not have the need to query other object's visibility. Use interfaces if you want to make sure an object has a guaranteed public API.

Comment: I've found that if I ever want to explicitly determine this information it means I need to refactor and change how I'm approaching the problem. OOP is about interfaces. You either have access to something or you don't. You shouldn't bother with the details of methods/properties that are behind the curtain.

Comment: iI need it for the magic __get which allows you to get `$object->testProperty` if there's a public method `getTestProperty()` in that object.. //I edited the question

Comment: not an answer but my advise would be to get rid of magic getters. They make your API hard to figure out and are unneeded toys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`is_callable`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-callable.php) to check if the method can be called on the object:

```
is_callable(array($object, 'methodName'))
```

If you need to check for some property existence use [`property_exists`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.property-exists.php):

```
property_exists($someObject', 'userId')
```

And finaly there are [`method_exists`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.method-exists.php):

```
method_exists('someClass', 'someMethod');
```

Comment: Note that `is_callable` will also return `TRUE` for magic methods that don't actually exist but are nevertheless callable and `property_exists` will return `TRUE` for private properties, so it won't tell you anything about the accessibility of the property.

Answer (score 0):

There is also 2 useful functions:
bool method_exists(class_name_or_object,method_name) - will return true if method **exists** (public and even protected and private) either false 
array get_class_methods(class_name_or_object) - return array of public methods of class or object